# ViewPager has bad offset data after rotating the screen when the current page is not the first

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

### **App Structure:**

My app has a single `FragmentActivity`, and that `FragmentActivity` hosts a `Fragment` which hosts a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` has an adapter which subclasses `FragmentStatePagerAdapater`, and that adapter overrides `getItem()` to return a new Fragment based on the position; `getCount()` is set to always return 2.

### **The Problem:**

The app works just fine up until either of two things happens: A rotation occurs when the ViewPager is displaying the second Fragment, or if, in `onResume()`, the ViewPager is told to scroll to a page other the the first. As far as I can tell, these scenarios are identical. When one of those events occurs, scrolling has stopped, and the visible Fragment is the second of the Fragments being managed by the ViewPager, **the `onPageScrolled(int, float, int)` callback is called with the 'position' argument still at '0' (it should be 1) and the 'positionOffset' argument set to '1' (which is outside the the [0,1) range as promised in the docs).** I did some poking around in the ViewPager code and discovered that the `boolean pageScrolled(int xpos)` function goes from being called with values in the range of [0,940] (0 on the first page and then 940 on the second) to being being called with values in the range [-940,0] (-940 on the first, 0 on the second). If the ViewPager were being reset to think that the second page was the first page, then this actually makes sense (sort of), although it's not at all what I want.

### **Some Code:**

ViewPagerFragment (hosts the ViewPager). MyViewPager is just a copy/paste of the support library's ViewPager; I wanted to print out some of the data from its private methods.

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment implements MyViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

@InjectView(R.id.view_pager) MyViewPager viewPager;

@DebugLog
public ViewPagerFragment() {
    setRetainInstance(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this,view);
    Log.d("onCreateView()","ViewPagerFragment = "+this.toString());
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setupPager();
}

void setupPager(){
    if(viewPager != null) {
        if (viewPager.getAdapter() == null) {
            viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        viewPager.setPageMargin(40);
    }
}

@Override
@DebugLog
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
    ButterKnife.reset(this);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    if(positionOffset == 1f){
        Log.d("onPageScrolled","position offset == 1 and position == "+position+". That's bad!");
    } else if(position == 1){
        Log.d("onPageScrolled","position offset == "+positionOffset+" and position == 1. That's good!");
    }

}

public static class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    @DebugLog
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

}

My question, in case it isn't implied, is **'What have I done to mess up my ViewPager, and how can I fix it?'** Removing the `setRetainInstance()` call will obviously reset things to normal, but then I lose my 'place' in the ViewPager. Removing the `setRetainInstance()` call and then using `Bundle savedInstanceState` to preserve the ViewPager position also doesn't work (as mentioned at the top of my post).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use `viewPager.setPageMargin(40);`  ?

Comment: Is calling setPageMargin a problem? I'm not calling it for any particular reason (other than to set the margin ...).

Comment: Wow... I have exactly the same issue. For now I couldn't solve this but how about reinitializing the ViewPager when the rotation happen? I thought it might be huge for reinitiate but It could be part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug on ViewPager after rotation.

I calculate the scrollX(offset) of current page, and It always be 0 when one page scrolling is done.

However, It comes to 1 or X(around the page width, 938~9 if the page width  is 940) after rotation.

I've had some issues on `onPageScrolled` when the device rotated, and I solved these by calling `setAdapter` again on rotation callback like `onConfigurationChanged`.

Here are some code blocks. `Device` is my custom class.

```
public void configOnOrientationChange() {
    if (Device.isPortrait(getContext())) {
        configOnPortraitOrientation();
    } else if (Device.isLandscape(getContext())) {
        configOnLandscapeOrientation();
    }

    int currentItem = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (mPagerAdapter != null) {
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Override onSizeChanged method of ViewPager like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
         beginFakeDrag();
        fakeDragBy(0);
        endFakeDrag();
    }
```